# OriginLab - Smart Import of ASCII

Tags: originlab

I recorded a measurement of 50 scans and obtained an ASCII file with the values in it. The fifth column is the number of the scan. How can I import this ASCII file and have each scan in a new column?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OriginLab support Team has answered to this question. With the 2017 version one column can be used as reference to split the worksheet or unstack columns. This is embedded in the "split mode" or in the "column group".